# How to use proxy with selenium-webdriver ruby?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "selenium-proxy"

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.proxy = Selenium::Proxy.new(:http => "proxify.com:8080")

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :http_client => client)
```

Getting Below Error:

proxy-test.rb:7:in `': uninitialized constant Selenium::Proxy (NameError)

Note :  i have already installed

```
gem install selenium-webdriver

gem install selenium-proxy
```

selenium webdriver is working without proxy. when i am using proxy, getting 
uninitialized constant Selenium::Proxy (NameError).

Answer (score 0):

It is `Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy` and not `Selenium::Proxy`.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(http: UR_PROXY_URL)
```